# AMP in web browser

Tags: android, web, browser, amp-html

I'm new to AMP, read docs but couldn't figure out few things. My ques is
I'm trying to build an Android web browser and want to display amp pages for every website user want to open. I know it is in the hands of website developers to convert their HTML to Amp-HTML
But what I want for my web browser, I'll convert those websites to Amp-HTML and display them. No matter if some of the functionalities of websites is not working or other things. I want to get it start by displaying Text and photos in the website, like sort of google web lite.
Also, I'm very new to these things. Kindly help me to find the right track if I'm misleading on something

Comment: This question is too broad.  Please do some research then ask a specific question, showing the code you already have.

Comment: I would recommend you to take look at https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/create

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take look at https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/create first.

You need to follow the specific HTML markup rule to make AMP HTML such as  which you mentioned. After you make your own AMP HTML template, you can use here to validate your amp page. https://validator.ampproject.org/ Also you can add `#development=1` in your URL make your chrome devtool to validate as well.

After you create AMP HTML, deploy to the live site. Then Google would cache your site. After your site is cached – Google AMP Cache, your site would load very fast.